# How find first empty row without .activate or .select?

Tags: excel, vba

I need to copy data from one workbook to another over time.
So I open the second workbook several times a month and look for the first empty row and add some data with for cycle.

```
Workbooks(wName).Activate    
  for cycle = 1 to 10
firstEmptyRow = (Workbooks(wName).Worksheets("sName").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row) + 1

Workbooks(wName).Worksheets("sName").Range("A" & (firstEmptyRow)) = myData1 'from userForm
Workbooks(wName).Worksheets("sName").Range("B" & (firstEmptyRow)) = myData2
 next cycle
```

But is there a beter way?
Without `.Activate` and without `.Select`?

What is the best practice?
I only found this `.End(xlUp)` code

Comment: that is one of the reccomendes ways to get the last row. It is basically equivalent to going to the last possible row of excel and then press `Ctrl`+`Up` in the defined column.

Comment: I work with multiple workbooks and try to avoid "accidents" caused .Select .Activate and similar.

Comment: [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-excel-with-vba

Answer (score 0):

In general, when working with several Workbooks, try to save them in objects. For example

```vb
Sub copy()
    Dim wbCopyTo As Workbook, wbCopyFrom As Workbook
    Dim wsCopyTo As Worksheet, wsCopyFrom As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim cycle As Long
    
    Set wbCopyTo = ThisWorkbook 'ThisWorkbook is the workbook the macro lives in
    Set wbCopyFrom = Workbooks.Open("path_to_workbook")
    
    Set wsCopyTo = wbCopyFrom.Worksheets("sName")
    
    'Do Stuff and get myData1 and myData2
    
    With wsCopyTo
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        
        For cycle = 1 To 10
            .Cells(lastRow + cycle, 1).Value = myData1
            .Cells(lastRow + cycle, 2).Value = myData2
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

I stored the worksheet in an object and will always be sure that the reference is correct.

Answer (score 0):

### First Available Row

- Adjust the values in the constants section.
- The `Cycle - myData_` stuff makes little sense here, but the focus is set to the 'handling' of `dCell` anyway.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub backupData()

    Const dwbPath As String = "C:\Test\Backup.xlsx"
    Const dwsName As String = "sName"
    Const dFirst As String = "A2"
    
    ' Open the workbook if it's not already open.
    Dim dwb As Workbook: Set dwb = Workbooks.Open(dwbPath)
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = dwb.Worksheets(dwsName)
    
    ' Create a reference to the first available cell. This will search
    ' the complete worksheet i.e. if the last value in column `A` is in row `5`,
    ' and the last value in column `C` is in row `7`, then cell `A8`
    ' will be referenced.
    Dim dCell As Range: Set dCell = dws.Range(dFirst)
    With dCell
        Dim lCell As Range
        Set lCell = .Resize(.Worksheet.Rows.Count - .Row + 1, _
            .Worksheet.Columns.Count - .Column + 1) _
            .Find("*", , xlFormulas, , xlByRows, xlPrevious)
        If Not lCell Is Nothing Then
            Set dCell = .Offset(lCell.Row - .Row + 1)
            'Debug.Print lCell.Address, dCell.Address
        End If
    End With
    
    ' Remove those two.
    Const myData1 As Long = 0
    Const myData2 As Long = 1
    
    Dim Cycle As Long
    For Cycle = 1 To 10
        dCell.Value = myData1
        dCell.Offset(, 1) = myData2
        Set dCell = dCell.Offset(1)
    Next Cycle

End Sub
```